# How to assign array length to a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple bash script that adds integers and supplies the sum. I figured the easiest way would be to assign the input to an array. Then traverse the array to perform the summation. I need to use the length of the array in my for loop and cannot figure out how to assign the array length to a variable.

Any help appreciated on the simple script (which I did to learn bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
# add1 : adding user supplied ints

echo -n "Please enter any number of integers: "
read -a input

echo "Your input is ${input[*]}"
echo "${#input[@]} number of elements"

num = ${#input[@]}   # causing error
for ((i = 0; i < "${num}"; ++i )); do  # causing error
  sum = $((sum + input[$i]))
done

echo "The sum of your input is $sum"
```

Which yields the errors:

```
line 10: num: command not found 
line 11: ((: i < :syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< ")
```

Comment: [Here is more information](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html) on assignment conventions in Bash :)

Comment: You say "causing error"; it would be helpful to know what error it is causing.

Comment: @msw - Already solved. Thanks for the feedback. The error was:
line 10: num: command not found
line 11: ((: i < : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< ")

Comment: In the future, you should include (or edit) that into your question.

Answer (score 10):

You just have a syntax error. Remove the space before `=`:

```
num = ${#input[@]}   # causing error
```

becomes:

```
num=${#input[@]}   # works
```

Note that if you assign to a variable in bash using the `=` operator, there MUST NOT be any space before and after the `=`

Read [this entry about Variable Assignment in the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works. I had the same error throughout the program. And I feel like an idiot. Coming from C++ where that space doesn't matter...

Comment: don't worry about that. every bash coder has once seen this error ;)